# ASP.NET MVC - Complex Queries

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm new at MVC and I'm trying to find a strong architecture for a complex projet I'm going to be designing.

Coming from an ASP 2.0 background where the Data Layer and Business Logic are built using a traditional three tier architecture I'm finding it hard to understand how to map the three tier system that I know well onto the ASP.NET/MVC model.

I'm used to building classes in the data layer and running SQL stored procedures - so what I'd like to know is how to build these sort of things in the ASP.NET/MVC model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget all you learnt with ASP and VB apart from the base concepts like layers and learn about MVC, MVVM and LINQ, probably with Entity Framework for the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Look up creating CLR functions on SQL Server.  You can create an object with helper methods that SQL Server can use to do all sorts of data manipulation, then use the results in queries.  Here's a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx